# Fabric -f option not working

Tags: git, bash, deployment, fabric

I've been using Fabric successfully from my local machine for a while now and finally have a decent deploy script that I'd like to call during a post-receive hook for git.  In order to accomplish this I have the following code, all of which is verified up until the `fab` command:

```
deploy=... # CODE TO DETERMINE IF YOU SHOULD DEPLOY

if [[ $deploy ]] ; then
  TMPFILE="/tmp/$(basename $0).$$.tmp"
  git cat-file blob release:fabfile.py > $TMPFILE
  fab -f $TMPFILE deploy:servername.mycompany.com
  rm $TMPFILE
fi
```

I've checked each step of the way, and I'm positive that TMPFILE is being created correctly (it contains my fabfile).  Manually running the steps above w/ a made up file in /tmp/ results in the same behavior.

The worst part is that it "reminds" me that I can use `-f` to specify a fabfile...which I am.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to say `$TMPFILE` instead of `$TFILE`?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, but so's my script... thanks for the sharp eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it wants a file with the .py at the end. Change your temp file to use this file extension and it will work. It's an artifact most likely of fab's wanting to allow people to use python style directory classes like `fabfile/__init__.py` would be picked up with a `-f fabfile`

Example of this behavior here:

```
╭─mgoose@Macintosh  ~
╰─$ fab -f tmp.py test
[localhost] local: whoami
mgoose

Done.
╭─mgoose@Macintosh  ~
╰─$ mv tmp.py tmp.py.tmp
╭─mgoose@Macintosh  ~
╰─$ fab -f tmp.py.tmp test

Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.
╭─mgoose@Macintosh  ~
╰─$ cat tmp.py.tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1 ↵
from fabric.api import local, task

@task
def test():
    local("whoami")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl and let you know my results.

Comment: Side note: is this documented somewhere, or should I tweak the docs?

Comment: So now it's running, but it doesn't like the filename (I think): `No module named post-receive.12345`  +1, accept.  Trying w/out the `dot` which has special meaning in python.

Comment: That made it work.  Thanks for your help.  Apparently fabric can't handle any special characters in the filename, and needs a `.py` file.

Comment: It might be good yes to add a note to the docs section for fabfile flags and discovery. Though the [note here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/usage/fabfiles.html#fabfile-discovery)  after the fact is related to this, but you'd be well served to add a more explicit example of good and bad names.

Comment: It's very clear for usages w/out the -f option. This is not clear, though: "The specific name to be searched for may be overridden on the command-line with the -f option ... For example, if you wanted to name your fabfile fab_tasks.py, you could create such a file and then call fab -f fab_tasks.py <task name> ... If the given fabfile name contains path elements other than a filename (e.g. ../fabfile.py or /dir1/dir2/custom_fabfile) it will be treated as a file path and directly checked for existence without any sort of searching." Seems like you should be able to use any name at all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on both my fabric questions.